# Symlinks on windows

Tags: python, windows, symlink

I'm trying to check is the path **symlink hardlink** or junction point on windows
How can I do it? `os.path.islink()` not work. It always returns `False`
I create symlinks by next method:

```
mklink /d linkPath targetDir
mklink /h linkPath targetDir    
mklink /j linkPath targetDir
```

I've used command line because os.link and os.symlink available only on Unix systems

Maybe there are any command line tools for it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The `os.path.islink()` docstring states:

```
Test for symbolic link.
On WindowsNT/95 and OS/2 always returns false
```

In Windows the links are ending with `.lnk`, for files and folders, so you could create a function adding this extension and checking with `os.path.isfile()` and `os.path.isfolder()`, like:

```
mylink = lambda path: os.path.isfile(path + '.lnk') or  os.path.isdir(path + '.lnk')
```

Comment: I think it not correct. At least because I need in a link to folder also. Also extension does not guarantee what path is symlink or not

Comment: Thank you but it does not guarantee me that path is symlink. I would like to check all paths.

Comment: How this answer got 3 upvotes is beyond me. The extension has absolutely zip to do with whether something is considered a link or not. Also, .lnk files are merely a left-over from the "good" old days of Windows 98, when Windows didn't support anything remotely resembling symbolic links like UNIX / Linux had for ages.

Comment: @antred I understand your critic... unfortunately I could not come up with a better answer. Do you have something better in mind? Why do you think this answer does not address the OP's question?

Comment: @SaulloCastro: because shortcuts are NOT symbolic links!

Answer (score 1):

This works on Python 3.3 on Windows 8.1 using an NTFS filesystem.

islink() returns True for a symlink (as created with mklink) and False for a normal file.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from https://eklausmeier.wordpress.com/2015/10/27/working-with-windows-junctions-in-python/
(see also: [Having trouble implementing a readlink() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27972776/having-trouble-implementing-a-readlink-function))

```py
from ctypes import WinDLL, WinError
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD, LPCWSTR

kernel32 = WinDLL('kernel32')

GetFileAttributesW = kernel32.GetFileAttributesW
GetFileAttributesW.restype = DWORD
GetFileAttributesW.argtypes = (LPCWSTR,) #lpFileName In

INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES = 0xFFFFFFFF
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 0x00400

def islink(path):
    result = GetFileAttributesW(path)
    if result == INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES:
        raise WinError()
    return bool(result & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = "C:\\Programme" # "C:\\Program Files" on a German Windows.
    b = islink(path)
    print path, 'is link:', b
```