# Having trouble implementing a readlink() function

Tags: python, ctypes, symlink, junction, readlink

I've been trying to figure out a way to get some sort of ability to be able to return the true abspath of a symbolic link in Windows, under Python 2.7. (I cannot upgrade to 3.x, as most DCCs such as Maya/3ds max do not use that version of Python)

I've looked at the sid0 ntfs utils (whose islink() function works, but readlink() function always returns an empty unicode string for me for some reason), and the juntalis ntfs libs (which unfortunately, I couldn't get to work), along with a helpful script someone posted:

```
import os, ctypes, struct
from ctypes import windll, wintypes

FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT = 0x900a8

FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY      = 0x0001
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN        = 0x0002
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY     = 0x0010
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL        = 0x0080
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 0x0400


GENERIC_READ  = 0x80000000
GENERIC_WRITE = 0x40000000
OPEN_EXISTING = 3
FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x80
FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT = 0x00200000
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value

INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES = 0xFFFFFFFF

FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT = 2097152
FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS = 33554432
# FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTI
FILE_FLAG_REPARSE_BACKUP = 35651584


GetFileAttributes = windll.kernel32.GetFileAttributesW
_CreateFileW = windll.kernel32.CreateFileW
_DevIoCtl = windll.kernel32.DeviceIoControl
_DevIoCtl.argtypes = [
    wintypes.HANDLE, #HANDLE hDevice
    wintypes.DWORD, #DWORD dwIoControlCode
    wintypes.LPVOID, #LPVOID lpInBuffer
    wintypes.DWORD, #DWORD nInBufferSize
    wintypes.LPVOID, #LPVOID lpOutBuffer
    wintypes.DWORD, #DWORD nOutBufferSize
    ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.DWORD), #LPDWORD lpBytesReturned
    wintypes.LPVOID] #LPOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped
_DevIoCtl.restype = wintypes.BOOL


def islink(path):
    # assert os.path.isdir(path), path
    if GetFileAttributes(path) & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT:
        return True
    else:
        return False


def DeviceIoControl(hDevice, ioControlCode, input, output):
    # DeviceIoControl Function
    # http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx
    if input:
        input_size = len(input)
    else:
        input_size = 0
    if isinstance(output, int):
        output = ctypes.create_string_buffer(output)
    output_size = len(output)
    assert isinstance(output, ctypes.Array)
    bytesReturned = wintypes.DWORD()
    status = _DevIoCtl(hDevice, ioControlCode, input,
                       input_size, output, output_size, bytesReturned, None)
    print "status(%d)" % status
    if status != 0:
        return output[:bytesReturned.value]
    else:
        return None


def CreateFile(path, access, sharemode, creation, flags):
    return _CreateFileW(path, access, sharemode, None, creation, flags, None)


SymbolicLinkReparseFormat = "LHHHHHHL"
SymbolicLinkReparseSize = struct.calcsize(SymbolicLinkReparseFormat);

def readlink(path):
    """ Windows readlink implementation. """
    # This wouldn't return true if the file didn't exist, as far as I know.
    assert islink(path)
    # assert type(path) == unicode

    # Open the file correctly depending on the string type.
    hfile = CreateFile(path, GENERIC_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING,
                       FILE_FLAG_REPARSE_BACKUP)
    # MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 16384 = (16*1024)
    buffer = DeviceIoControl(hfile, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, None, 16384)
    windll.CloseHandle(hfile)

    # Minimum possible length (assuming length of the target is bigger than 0)
    if not buffer or len(buffer) < 9:
        return None

    # Only handle SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer
    (tag, dataLength, reserver, SubstituteNameOffset, SubstituteNameLength,
     PrintNameOffset, PrintNameLength,
     Flags) = struct.unpack(SymbolicLinkReparseFormat,
                            buffer[:SymbolicLinkReparseSize])
    print tag, dataLength, reserver, SubstituteNameOffset, SubstituteNameLength
    start = SubstituteNameOffset + SymbolicLinkReparseSize
    actualPath = buffer[start : start + SubstituteNameLength].decode("utf-16")
    # This utf-16 string is null terminated
    index = actualPath.find(u"\0")
    assert index > 0
    if index > 0:
        actualPath = actualPath[:index]
    if actualPath.startswith(u"?\\"):
        return actualPath[2:]
    else:
        return actualPath
```

However, most of the time various solutions I've tried end up giving me:

[Error 126] The specified module could not be found

Even though I am able to import ctypes and do stuff such as importing cdll:

```
libc = cdll.msvcrt
libc.printf
<_FuncPtr object at 0x0000000002A9F388>
```

I'm pretty new to this part of Python and ctypes in general, so any pointers on dealing with symbolic links here would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ERROR_MOD_NOT_FOUND` (126) is likely due to `windll.CloseHandle(hfile)`, which tries to load "closehandle.dll". It's missing `kernel32`.

Here's an alternate implementation that handles junctions as well as symbolic links.

**ctypes definitions**

```python
import ctypes
from ctypes import wintypes

kernel32 = ctypes.WinDLL('kernel32', use_last_error=True)

FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES = 0x0080
OPEN_EXISTING = 3
FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT = 0x00200000
FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS   = 0x02000000
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT = 0x0400

IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT = 0xA0000003
IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK     = 0xA000000C
FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT    = 0x000900A8
MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE = 0x4000

LPDWORD = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.DWORD)
LPWIN32_FIND_DATA = ctypes.POINTER(wintypes.WIN32_FIND_DATAW)
INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE = wintypes.HANDLE(-1).value

def IsReparseTagNameSurrogate(tag):
    return bool(tag & 0x20000000)

def _check_invalid_handle(result, func, args):
    if result == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

def _check_bool(result, func, args):
    if not result:
        raise ctypes.WinError(ctypes.get_last_error())
    return args

kernel32.FindFirstFileW.errcheck = _check_invalid_handle
kernel32.FindFirstFileW.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
kernel32.FindFirstFileW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR,  # _In_  lpFileName
    LPWIN32_FIND_DATA) # _Out_ lpFindFileData

kernel32.FindClose.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # _Inout_ hFindFile

kernel32.CreateFileW.errcheck = _check_invalid_handle
kernel32.CreateFileW.restype = wintypes.HANDLE
kernel32.CreateFileW.argtypes = (
    wintypes.LPCWSTR, # _In_     lpFileName
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_     dwDesiredAccess
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_     dwShareMode
    wintypes.LPVOID,  # _In_opt_ lpSecurityAttributes
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_     dwCreationDisposition
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_     dwFlagsAndAttributes
    wintypes.HANDLE)  # _In_opt_ hTemplateFile 

kernel32.CloseHandle.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,) # _In_ hObject

kernel32.DeviceIoControl.errcheck = _check_bool
kernel32.DeviceIoControl.argtypes = (
    wintypes.HANDLE,  # _In_        hDevice
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_        dwIoControlCode
    wintypes.LPVOID,  # _In_opt_    lpInBuffer
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_        nInBufferSize
    wintypes.LPVOID,  # _Out_opt_   lpOutBuffer
    wintypes.DWORD,   # _In_        nOutBufferSize
    LPDWORD,          # _Out_opt_   lpBytesReturned
    wintypes.LPVOID)  # _Inout_opt_ lpOverlapped 

class REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER(ctypes.Structure):
    class ReparseData(ctypes.Union):
        class LinkData(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_ = (('SubstituteNameOffset', wintypes.USHORT),
                        ('SubstituteNameLength', wintypes.USHORT),
                        ('PrintNameOffset',      wintypes.USHORT),
                        ('PrintNameLength',      wintypes.USHORT))
            @property
            def PrintName(self):
                dt = wintypes.WCHAR * (self.PrintNameLength //
                                       ctypes.sizeof(wintypes.WCHAR))
                name = dt.from_address(ctypes.addressof(self.PathBuffer) +
                                       self.PrintNameOffset).value
                if name.startswith(r'\??'):
                    name = r'\\?' + name[3:] # NT => Windows
                return name
        class SymbolicLinkData(LinkData):
            _fields_ = (('Flags',      wintypes.ULONG),
                        ('PathBuffer', wintypes.BYTE * 0))
        class MountPointData(LinkData):
            _fields_ = (('PathBuffer', wintypes.BYTE * 0),)
        class GenericData(ctypes.Structure):
            _fields_ = (('DataBuffer', wintypes.BYTE * 0),)
        _fields_ = (('SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer', SymbolicLinkData),
                    ('MountPointReparseBuffer',   MountPointData),
                    ('GenericReparseBuffer',      GenericData))
    _fields_ = (('ReparseTag',        wintypes.ULONG),
                ('ReparseDataLength', wintypes.USHORT),
                ('Reserved',          wintypes.USHORT),
                ('ReparseData',       ReparseData))
    _anonymous_ = ('ReparseData',)
```

**functions**

```python
def islink(path):
    data = wintypes.WIN32_FIND_DATAW()
    kernel32.FindClose(kernel32.FindFirstFileW(path, ctypes.byref(data)))
    if not data.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_REPARSE_POINT:
        return False
    return IsReparseTagNameSurrogate(data.dwReserved0)

def readlink(path):
    n = wintypes.DWORD()
    buf = (wintypes.BYTE * MAXIMUM_REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER_SIZE)()
    flags = FILE_FLAG_OPEN_REPARSE_POINT | FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS
    handle = kernel32.CreateFileW(path, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, 0, None,
                OPEN_EXISTING, flags, None)
    try:
        kernel32.DeviceIoControl(handle, FSCTL_GET_REPARSE_POINT, None, 0,
            buf, ctypes.sizeof(buf), ctypes.byref(n), None)
    finally:
        kernel32.CloseHandle(handle)
    rb = REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER.from_buffer(buf)
    tag = rb.ReparseTag
    if tag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_SYMLINK:
        return rb.SymbolicLinkReparseBuffer.PrintName
    if tag == IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT:
        return rb.MountPointReparseBuffer.PrintName
    if not IsReparseTagNameSurrogate(tag):
        raise ValueError("not a link")
    raise ValueError("unsupported reparse tag: %d" % tag)
```

**example**

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) 
[MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]'
>>> os.system(r'mklink /d spam C:\Windows')
symbolic link created for spam <<===>> C:\Windows
0
>>> islink('spam')
True
>>> readlink('spam')
u'C:\\Windows'
>>> islink('C:/Documents and Settings') # junction
True
>>> readlink('C:/Documents and Settings')
u'C:\\Users'
>>> islink('C:/Users/All Users') # symlinkd
True
>>> readlink('C:/Users/All Users')
u'C:\\ProgramData'
```

Comment: This worked OOTB like a charm! I don't like to do this, but for someone starting out with ctypes (and the Windows API in general), would you recommend any other sources other than MSDN for a beginner to kind of wrap my head around how to work with ctypes? I'm finding it a little difficult to understand some of the docs.... In any case, thanks for helping out!

Comment: I modelled my answer closely on CPython's [`win_readlink`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/ab2c023a9432/Modules/posixmodule.c#l7396), but extended to support junctions.

Comment: Do you have an example of something in the [ctypes tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#ctypes-tutorial) or MSDN docs that's difficult? For C programming in general, have you seen the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com)?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the resources! I actually did do some of the ctypes stuff (just writing a simple .c lib and getting access to its methods via ctypes), but I've never heard of Structure or Union classes before (I'm not that experienced in C/C++), so trying to wrap my head around all that in the code provided is a bit daunting...I'm still looking at the tutorial but I think I'll probably understand more once I find time and do a few simple exercises to figure out what's going on. Again, thanks so much! :D

Comment: It's soooo great! I was looking for such function for a few months! Your solution is the best!

Answer (score 1):

This is implemented in Tcl as `file readlink` and the implementation of this might be worth reading as there seem to be a few differences. The [`WinReadLinkDirectory`](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/master/win/tclWinFile.c#L530) function calls [`NativeReadReparse`](https://github.com/tcltk/tcl/blob/master/win/tclWinFile.c#L663) to read the `REPARSE_DATA_BUFFER` but this uses different flags to the `CreateFile` function. Also the buffer size is different I think and the size of structures in Win32 calls is often used to detect the version of the API used so it is likely worth taking care to set the size to the correct value (or possibly the same value used in the Tcl implementation).

Just to show what I mean by Tcl support for this:

```
C:\>dir
 Directory of C:\

22/09/2014  14:29    <JUNCTION>     Code [C:\src]
...

C:\>tclsh
% file readlink Code
C:\src
```